# Отображается только та часть сайта, которая сразу помещается на экране

Tags: вёрстка, html, дизайн, css

Делается адаптивный сайт.
При просмотре в мобильных браузерах вот что получаем:
[image]
[image]

Т.е. грузиться только та часть сайта, как предварительно помещается в экран.
Скролим дальше - белая область. 
У кого-то была такая проблема?

Comment: У кого-то была такая проблема?

Comment: Вы не забыли? - 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-  scale=1.0">

?

Comment: И еще, у Вас восемь заданных вопросов, и ни один из них не принят...

Может пора изменить свое отношение к ХэшКод'у?

Comment: нет  <meta name=  есть  
В чем может быть еще ошибка?

Comment: вопроси приму))

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, **background** у Вас прописан для **body**!?

Используйте следующие правила **CSS** для **body**, **html**:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ececec; /*Ваш background (с цветом могу ошибаться...)*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

И будет Вам счастье!

Удачи

---

**P.S.** В случае, если background прописан для другого элемента, то используете выше указанные правила для него.

---

**P.S.2** Если я неправильно понял Ваш вопрос и проблема в не отображении ниже идущего контента, то давайте посмотрим Ваш код.

Код, желательно разместить на jsfiddle.net